# How to let Gmail only send notifications and not allow the features like Find My Phone?

Tags: gmail, google-apps, location-services

I have a Gmail account and 7 of my friends including me have added the google account to our android devices. However, it can be used for the features like Find My Phone and subsequently can be used to erase the data if any one of us wishes to do so.

So, how do I make that Gmail account just send me notifications for new emails, and not allow it to trace my phone using features like Find My Phone? I have searched in the web, but didn't get any way to achieve what I want. Any suggestions regarding this would be of much help to me.

In other words, is there a way to add the Gmail account like just another email account (e.g. Outlook etc.) in our devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways of using a Gmail account on your phone without linking it to your device (avoiding contacts sync, device manager concerns etc) :

- Configure Gmail as IMAP. See [How to add Gmail account without adding Google account on Android](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/16222360/how-to-add-gmail-account-without-adding-google-account-on-android?hl=en) for instructions.
- Use a mail client that allows you to add Gmail accounts . I use an excellent open source client, [FairEmail](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2656/131553) to add multiple Gmail accounts (also other mail providers) ( See [FAQ](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/blob/master/FAQ.md#user-content-faq6) for help). Free version is good enough for your purposes.

Both these methods don't link the mail account to your device and therefore cannot be used for Find my phone, contact sync etc.

**Note:** First remove the account from your device and then use either options

Comment: The first way did it for me. However, I was not able to sign in using the default email client of my phone via Personal (IMAP) way at the first go, and tried 2-3 times again but to no avail. Finally, while configuring the ``outgoing server setting``, I ``unchecked/turned-off`` the **Require sign in** option and it did the trick.