# Sync two gmail accounts, but only one account's contacts in Mi10i

Tags: contacts, xiaomi, mi

In earlier models we had option to sync selective items like only Gmail and not Contacts of an account being added to phone, but now If I add 2nd account, by default it syncs all data(gmail, contacts etc while adding itself).And there is no option to remove the synced contacts of one account. Please help in this regards.
In Mi10i the manufacturer had made the OS in such a way, from whichever app I add a google account it just launches same "account adding screen(may be from play services)" and no option but to agree for play services to use this signin in all google apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to let Gmail only send notifications and not allow the features like Find My Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239069/how-to-let-gmail-only-send-notifications-and-not-allow-the-features-like-find-my)

Comment: @beeshyams That answer did not help me. Actually in Mi10i the manufacture had made the os in such a way, from whichever app I add a google account it just launches same "account adding screen(may be from play services)" and no option but to agree for play services to use this signin in all google apps.

Comment: I don't know about Xiaomi devices, but usually there is an Accounts menu on the Android Settings where you can configure which data you want to sync or not.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes I can control future Sync. but could not find way to prevent sync when adding account first time. / also no option to undo the sync that was done first time when adding the account.

Answer (score 0):

As AndrewT mentioned, you can select the items that you want to sync. To prevent sync when adding the account for the first time, you can [turn off the sync toggle in quick settings](https://xiaomi.eu/community/attachments/screenshot_2020-03-23-22-23-47-432_com-android-browser-jpg.28858/) before adding the account.

Comment: No this option doesn't work in Mi10i. In settings even if sync is turned off.(Note in the new Mui there is no quick sync icon as in screenshot. But I went into settings and turned off Auto sync) And then added gmail account, but that synced contacts as well.